# PostgresSQL pagination, tuning indexes and order by

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, index-tuning, order-by

I have a table with those columns: id, uuid, customer_id, building, dept, values

I have a combined index on those columns: `building, dept`.

The table contains ~80 millions of rows

I would like to apply a pagination on this basic query: `select * from my_table`.
So I have to introduce a unique column because that is the only way the order by correctness is guaranteed: `select * from my_table order by id asc offset 0 limit 1000`.
I used `limit` and `offset` even if there are other techniques like `> id`, ubt I think for now it is not important.

My problem is that now I have to introduce filters to this pagination, as it is expanding as a search feature. Then I have to filter by building and department.
Here the new query: `select * from my_table where building = 666 and dept = 'my_dept' order by id asc offset 0 limit 1000`.

Now in order to maintain the `order by` correctness I have to maintain the `order by id` clause but it is going to slow down the query (10+ minutes) as the id is not in the combined index.

The above table is just a small representation of a real table where it contains more fields , like 6 not so bad, but in order to maintain the order by id every index is not valid anymore or I should include the `id` field everywhere.

am I approaching in the wrong way?
Are here any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You won't be able to efficiently search for arbitrary criteria. Limit yourself to one or two and index those well.

Comment: By the time you are up to 6 fields, the number of rows left should be small enough that using a sort to do the ordering should be very fast.  If not, then add 'id' to that index as well